# Cómo puedo saber porqué en otra computadora distinta a la mía se ve mi sitio web desfasado por completo, ancho largo y las imágenes más chicas?

Tags: reactjs, css3

Repito: Cómo puedo saber porqué en otra computadora distinta a la mía se ve mi sitio web desfasado por completo, ancho largo y las imágenes más chicas?

Link al código: https://github.com/Franco-Carrera/ProyectoFermin

Comment: La respuesta puede ser varios: 1- no está optimizado para todos los navegadores (o los principales), 2- no es responsivo, 3- no realizaste una prueba en diferente navegadores y medidas, 4- y en App.css que creo que es el principal estilo, no hay ni @media queries ni estilos para Chrome ni Mozilla ni otros.

Comment: También hay que llevar en cuenta la pantalla de tu computadora en la que estás trabajando la página. Tu monitor puede ser muy grande, y entonces tú estilos trabajas por como ves en tu enorme monitor. O viceversa,.

Comment: Yo cuando hago un trabajo, pruebo el tres monitores: en la que trabajo, netbook (pequeño) y en monitor grande y en teléfono. Aunque hay otra opción en  el mismo navegador que se usa el trabajo, se puede usar el inspector para cambiar de vista